# List all numbers smaller in sorted array in O(n)

Tags: algorithm

I have two sorted arrays, I would like to find out how to list the count of the numbers in array 1 that are bigger than the numbers in array 2.

For example, [1,4,6,8] and  [4,6,7,9] would return 4 as 6 is bigger than 4 and 8 is bigger than 4,6,7. Currently the best way I can do this is in O(n^2) by looping over each array, however I'm not sure how to do it in O(n)

Comment: What language are you using? What is the expected output to your example? 1?

Comment: "6 is smaller than 4 and 8 is smaller than 4,6,7"? Not true.

Comment: My bad i had got confused, I have corrected it now, also I am using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two pointers should suffice, since the arrays are sorted. This logic is similar to the merge step of Merge Sort, we're just keeping a track of the number of elements here.
Time Complexity: `O(N)`

```py
a = [1,4,6,8]
b = [4,6,7,9]
l,r = 0,0
n,m = len(a), len(b)
ans = 0
while l<n and r<m:
    if a[l]>b[r]:
        ans += n-l
        r += 1
    else:
        l += 1
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `two-pointer technique`, we can keep two pointers - `p1` in the first list and `p2` in the second list. We keep on incrementing `p1` till the number at `p1` in `list1` is smaller than the number at `p2` in `list2`. Otherwise, just increment the count by number of elements we have to the right of `p1`

```python
def smaller_count(list1, list2):
    l1, l2, ans = len(list1), len(list2), 0
    # pointers in list1 and list2
    p1, p2 = 0, 0
    while p1 < l1 and p2 < l2:
        if list1[p1] > list2[p2]:
            ans += l1 - p1
            p2 += 1
        else:
            p1 += 1
    return ans
```

```
>>> smaller_count([1,4,6,8], [4,6,7,9])
4
>>> smaller_count([1,4,6,8], [0])
4
>>> smaller_count([1,4,6,8], [10])
0
>>> smaller_count([1,4,6,8], [0, 1, 2, 3])
13
```

Since we are iterating over the two lists only once, the complexity would be `O(len(list1) + len(list2))`